# Improving detail printing in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, tostring

I have the following code.
The log level is **INFO**.
How can we write the better code that the *toString* will not be executed ?

```
Set<Integer> resultUserIdsSet = new HashSet<>();
log.trace("userIdsSet={}", resultUserIdsSet.toString());
```

Note: The *resultUserIdsSet* contains milions of integers.

We use ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone is telling you to use a Supplier, but there is no need for that.  Just let the logger do the toString call:

```
log.trace("userIdsSet={}", resultUserIdsSet);
```

By removing `.toString()`, you are just passing a reference to the Set.  If the trace level is not enabled, the logger call returns immediately;  the cost is essentially negligible.

If and only if the trace level is enabled, then the logger will invoke `toString()` on the Set.

Answer (score 1):

What is "log"? Now all implementations allow passing supplier like it was mentioned in other answers. 
There is a [Fixed RFE](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371) for this in SLF4J, but please specify what exactly what is the library you're talking about, whats the version, and so forth.

For older versions is still possible to use the old construction like this:

```
if(log.isTraceEnabled()) {
    log.trace("userIdsSet={}", resultUserIdsSet.toString());
}
```

Now, regardless the support of `Supplier` that can really solve the issue, I would like to pay your attention to the note:

> Note: The resultUserIdsSet contains milions of integers.

This is quite problematic: 
If you place a logging statement like this, you really want that it will be printed at the level of trace. When trace is disabled (read almost always) - then you can avoid doing an expensive "toString" calculation like was mentioned in answers. However, then we enable the trace and it will create a million integers in set, many "interesting" things can happen:

- Millions integers are very expensive to be printed by appenders, both to console and to file, its really too much data and I/O operations are expensive.
- Even if you do print millions of integers it will be really challenging to understand something from this log.
- The things will aggravate if you print this in some kind of external for loop

Bottom line, think twice whether you really want to print all these ids. Maybe it makes sense  to truncate the output + provide some general purpose stats like number of ids in the set and so forth

Comment: We use ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3

Comment: I don't see that it supports lambdas in a general, so probably if(log.isTraceEnabled()) is the way to go.

Comment: In what log implementation and version the Supplier parameter exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading by supplier:

```
Set<Integer> resultUserIdsSet = new HashSet<>();
log.trace(() -> "userIdsSet=" + resultUserIdsSet);
```

Comment: We use ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3. and the overloading with Supplier doesn't exists. In what log and version the Supplier exists ?